# Nested If and For in algorithm2e

Tags: algorithm2e

I have the following code in algorithm2e with boxruled, vlined, and linesnumbered options. pdflatex gives me an empty line at the end of both the for loops inside the ifs. Can someone please suggest a way to get rid of the extra lines? Thanks.

```
\If {$\lfloor c\ (\log (n+1) - \log n) \rfloor > 1$}
{
    $u \leftarrow {\tt SampleControl}$\;
    $U \leftarrow \{ u \} \cup U_m$\;
}
${\tt ConnectState}(z, S_{n+1}, U, P_n, Q_n, \delta_n)$\;
\eIf{$\min_{u \in U} \Delta t_{n+1} (z_{n+1}, u) \leq \delta_n$}
{   $\delta_{n+1} = \delta_n/2$\;
    \For{$z \in S_{n+1}$}{
        ${\tt ConnectState}(z, S_{n+1}, U, P_{n+1}, Q_{n+1}, \delta_{n+1})$\;
}}{ $\delta_{n+1} \leftarrow \delta_n$\;
    \For{$z' \in Z_\mathrm{near}(z_{n+1})$}{
        ${\tt ConnectState}(z', S_{n+1}, U, P_{n+1}, Q_{n+1}, \delta_{n+1})$\;
}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please, add a minimal preamble to your code so that it becomes a complete example that can be run through LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you mean the additional vertical space at the end of the `if` and `for` blocks.
It can be configured by `\SetVlineSkip`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[boxruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\SetVlineSkip{0pt}      

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Caption of algorithm}
\If {$\lfloor c\ (\log (n+1) - \log n) \rfloor > 1$}
{
    $u \leftarrow {\tt SampleControl}$\;
    $U \leftarrow \{ u \} \cup U_m$\;
}
${\tt ConnectState}(z, S_{n+1}, U, P_n, Q_n, \delta_n)$\;
\eIf{$\min_{u \in U} \Delta t_{n+1} (z_{n+1}, u) \leq \delta_n$}
{   $\delta_{n+1} = \delta_n/2$\;
    \For{$z \in S_{n+1}$}{
        ${\tt ConnectState}(z, S_{n+1}, U, P_{n+1}, Q_{n+1},
\delta_{n+1})$\;
}}{ $\delta_{n+1} \leftarrow \delta_n$\;
    \For{$z' \in Z_\mathrm{near}(z_{n+1})$}{
        ${\tt ConnectState}(z', S_{n+1}, U, P_{n+1}, Q_{n+1},
\delta_{n+1})$\;
}}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

BTW, `\SetVlineSkip` is defined as:

```
\newcommand{\SetVlineSkip}[1]{\skiphlne=#1}%
```

A better definition for `\SetVlineSkip` would be (terminating of the assignment, support of package `calc`):

```
\renewcommand*{\SetVlineSkip}{\setlength{\skiphlne}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I however just realised that the extra vspace shows up if I use \IncMargin{} in ieeeconf.cls. It does not show up in the article class. Any suggestions to get incmargin and still remove the white space? :)

Comment: The class file is `IEEEconf.cls`. In `twocolumn` mode the line width is too small and you get overfull `\hbox` warnings. Fix them and then also the additional white space should disappear.

Comment: I solved this problem by reducing the font in the algorithm environment, saves more space for my paper and looks better as well!